# Trying to make a popup widget but get unknown errors instead

Tags: linux, lua, gnu, awesome-wm

So I've been trying to create a popup widget which should include 3 other widgets inside of it. I had to fix a bunch of things before I could get it to run without spitting out more errors. So I am at  the point where I am trying to run it to see if it really is working. I made a button(`day_button.lua`) which will trigger the visibility of the container(`empty-container.lua`). So I typed at the top of rc.lua: `local customclock = require("day_button")` which like I said gave no output of any errors. I tried to place the button in my wibar like so: [wibar](https://pastebin.com/c71y4wkS)(you can find it under the widget `mytextclock`). So by trying to "summon" the button I get these [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOrIF.png). I don't know what to do from this point forward. These errors aren't very helpful and I'm not that experienced.

I will also include [day_button.lua](https://pastebin.com/VU0bkZTN) and [empty-container.lua](https://pastebin.com/pyLp5Nrr) for better context.

Please help.

Comment: Please post your code in a code block to make it easier to see and thus easier to diagnose.

Comment: I tried but it looked weird in the preview which is why I used pastebin instead. Will try tho

Comment: I tried to include it in a code block. The format is not good looking and it certainly won't be easier to see let alone read.

Comment: Highlight the code. Then click the `{}` icon.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that you're indexing a local boolean value `v`. You may only index table values.

So you're doing someting like `v.someKey` or `v[somekey]` or `v:someKey` in the mentioned line.

`v` is probably part of a generic for loop. So you probably have a boolean value in a table where you expect a table value.

you know what you're doing wrong and you know where. The only thing that's left is to fix it. So find out why there is a boolean where you expect a table. If it should be a boolean, don't index it. If it should be a table, make sure it actually is a table.

Comment: It appears that I had to scrap a part of the code (which is the display_button. It didn't act as a button and I also had to return something at the end of the file). I modified `local button = {}` instead to `local button = wibox.widget {...}`. The error displayed above was and is completely irrelevant to what the actual issue was. On another note, If I knew what I was doing wrong and I knew where, I wouldn't have asked for help on this forum, or on any forum.

Comment: @xorg the error message tells you what you're doing wrong and where, you don't have to know that. that's what error messages are for. I'm a professional Lua programmer and I don't know what I'm doing wrong either, until the interpreter tells me.